# java module-info.java with kotlin package

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, javafx

This is all I did:

1. open IntelliJ community version, create new JavaFX application, select Gradle build and Kotlin language.
2. just use default package names com.example.demo1

after project created, build

Now it reports error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: C:\test\demo1\build\classes\java\main
```

Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Package com.example.demo1 not found in module

I noticed module-info.java is in java folder but all other source are in kotlin folder. Does that mean java file doesn't know the kotlin package?

If I remove module-info.java, it builds and runs. But module file is required to build artifacts, right?

Comment: No, a module descriptor is not necessary. If your application is written solely in Kotlin then I would suggest removing the `module-info.java` file. You'll just have to make sure JavaFX is loaded from the module-path via `--module-path` and `--add-modules` or by using a run-time image that includes JavaFX. But if your code is a mix of Java and Kotlin, then I believe the recommendation is to put the source files of both languages in the same source directory (`src/main/java`). In that case, you _might_ be able to have a module descriptor, but I don't know how well Kotlin and JPMS work together.

Comment: If you use Maven instead of Gradle in the wizard it works (can click on the green arrow in the gutter for the Application class and it will run).  But the same thing will fail if you choose Gradle, with the error you show.  You can still run the Gradle project by going to the Gradle window and double-clicking on Tasks | Application | run.  I think by default, intellij is too dumb to be able to correctly configure the run configuration for the JavaFX application in the IDE with a default new JavaFX project Gradle Kotlin build. File an enhancement request with IntelliJ about it if you want.